flutter_v2ray: No implementation found for void libv2ray.Libv2ray._init()
I'm using the url that works in the official v2ray app. The protocol is vless.
flutter_v2ray lib version 1.0.7
emulator pixel 6 android 12 api 31
on init
_flutterV2ray = FlutterV2ray(
      onStatusChanged: (status) {
        setState(() {
          _status = status;
        });
      },
    );

    await _flutterV2ray.initializeV2Ray();

When running this code it gives an error
if (await _flutterV2ray.requestPermission()) {
      _flutterV2ray.startV2Ray(
        remark: parser.remark,
        config: parser.getFullConfiguration(),
        blockedApps: null,
        bypassSubnets: null,
        proxyOnly: false,
      );
    }

error:
E/AndroidRuntime(10053): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10053): Process: com.example.outline_vpn:RunSoLibV2RayDaemon, PID: 10053
E/AndroidRuntime(10053): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void libv2ray.Libv2ray._init() (tried Java_libv2ray_Libv2ray__1init and Java_libv2ray_Libv2ray__1init__)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at libv2ray.Libv2ray._init(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at libv2ray.Libv2ray.<clinit>(Libv2ray.java:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at libv2ray.Libv2ray.newV2RayPoint(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at com.github.blueboytm.flutter_v2ray.v2ray.core.V2rayCoreManager.<init>(V2rayCoreManager.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at com.github.blueboytm.flutter_v2ray.v2ray.core.V2rayCoreManager.getInstance(V2rayCoreManager.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at com.github.blueboytm.flutter_v2ray.v2ray.services.V2rayVPNService.onCreate(V2rayVPNService.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4487)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:247)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(10053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

What could the problem be?

Did you find any solution? . I am also facing this problem.

@WaiHanKo I had to write native code for android using the dev7dev/V2ray-Android library. For ios I still don't know a solution
